# producing a variable for input into an RSS feed

Tags: python, debugging, variables, loops, python-2.7

this may be a very simple debugging question (I haven't been coding lone) I have a looping code that parses a scraped xml, this parsing happens on a 5 minute loop but doesn't return duplicates from one loop to the next, as a result of storing the user ids in a set, if the user id already exists in the userset then the script skips onto the next row of the xml. I am wanting to output the results of this script as an RSS, and I have a potential methodology to do so, however I first need to store the data as a variable of some sort.

I have attempted to do this, however each time I do I seem to run into problems with the last userid being stored in the set. Rather than providing you with my broken code I enclose an example of the working code, which does not include my hashed attempts to define the resulting prints as a variable.

```
import mechanize
import urllib
import json
import re
import random
import datetime
from sched import scheduler
from time import time, sleep

######Code to loop the script and set up scheduling time

s = scheduler(time, sleep)
random.seed()

def run_periodically(start, end, interval, func):
    event_time = start
    while event_time < end:
        s.enterabs(event_time, 0, func, ())
        event_time += interval + random.randrange(-5, 45)
    s.run()

###### Code to get the data required from the URL desired
def getData():  
    post_url = "URL OF INTEREST"
    browser = mechanize.Browser()
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

######These are the parameters you've got from checking with the aforementioned tools
    parameters = {'page' : '1',
              'rp' : '250',
              'sortname' : 'roi',
              'sortorder' : 'desc'
             }
#####Encode the parameters
    data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
    trans_array = browser.open(post_url,data).read().decode('UTF-8')

    xmlload1 = json.loads(trans_array)
    pattern1 = re.compile('>&nbsp;&nbsp;(.*)<')
    pattern2 = re.compile('/control/profile/view/(.*)\' title=')
    pattern3 = re.compile('<span style=\'font-size:12px;\'>(.*)<\/span>')

##### Making the code identify each row, removing the need to numerically quantify the     number of rows in the xmlfile,
##### thus making number of rows dynamic (change as the list grows, required for looping function to work un interupted)

    for row in xmlload1['rows']:
        cell = row["cell"]

##### defining the Keys (key is the area from which data is pulled in the XML) for use in the pattern finding/regex

        user_delimiter = cell['username']
        selection_delimiter = cell['race_horse']

        if strikeratecalc2 < 12 : continue;

##### REMAINDER OF THE REGEX DELMITATIONS

        username_delimiter_results = re.findall(pattern1, user_delimiter)[0]
        userid_delimiter_results = (re.findall(pattern2, user_delimiter)[0])
        user_selection = re.findall(pattern3, selection_delimiter)[0]

##### Code to stop duplicate posts of each user throughout the day

    userset = set ([])
    if userid_delimiter_results in userset: continue;

##### Printing the results of the code at hand

        print "user id = ",userid_delimiter_results
        print "username = ",username_delimiter_results
        print "user selection = ",user_selection
        print ""

##### Code to stop duplicate posts of each user throughout the day  part 2 (udating set to add users already printed to the ignore list)

    userset.update(userid_delimiter_results)

    getData()

    run_periodically(time()+5, time()+1000000, 300, getData)
```

The problem I had when trying to produce the variable (I tried to produce it as an array) was that somehow the code was missing the last userset.update(userid_delimiter_results) this resulted in the last entry in the feed being repeated on each run of the code, because according to the 'userset' the user id in question had not been logged. Any simple methods to enable me to output the results of this code as a variable would be greatly appreciated. Kind regards AEA

Comment: there are numerous issues e.g., the code always tries to test against an empty set (userset), the test itself might be also incorrect (or the later call to userset.update() is incorrect), the run_periodically call is unreachable due to infinite recursion (getData()). Split your code into tiny pieces and test them with a mock data individually until you understand what exactly each peace is doing. Consider using [scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html) to crawl, scrape data, and generate the feed or [scrapely](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapely) to extract data from an html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by making the print section into;

```
    arrayna = [arrayna1, arrayna2, arrayna3, arrayna4]

    arraym1 = "user id = ",userid_delimiter_results
```

Then in order to overcome the face that on each run of the loop arrayna would be

```
my_array = [] # Create an empty list

print(my_array)
```

So your code might look something like:

This worked :)